# Rejection of Build From Apple (iTune Connect)

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

Apple is saying

```
1. Build is invalid
2. ITC.app.preReleaseBuild.errors.invalidBinary
```

Is it because of of icon which comes in Build. See the following image

[image]

[image]

Can you see, icon is not showing any icon but apple own default icon.

Is it a cause of this invalid.

I tried

1. icon.png without Alpha/transparency
2. Compress images to NO
3. re-create apple certificates, apple is allowing me to archive, without any error.
4. I am not using any Launch Image, but LaunchScreen.storyboard.

So, can anyone tell me what is basic cause of this rejection from apple.

Thanks.

Comment: you cannot use the default icon for uploading a build to itunesconnect. you have to create your own. maybe just a simple placeholder-icon.

Comment: I am not using any default icon. I have all icons set in XCode, showing file in Developer and Ad-Hoc profile, but when I update to app store it shows me default, so from which account, It takes it.

Comment: @FinnFahrenkrug,  The actual issue that Apple is saying "ITC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.invalidBinary" .. What is this error. Please help

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods and using Swift for development ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Swift inside Objective-C (Charts library in Swift), also I am using CocoaPods for 6, 7 libraries.

Comment: target 'ProjectName' do

pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.5.7'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
pod 'DTTableViewManager'
pod 'AMScrollingNavbar', '~> 1.5'
pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
pod 'GPUImage', '~> 0.1.4'
pod 'Shapes', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'Charts'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
pod 'libPusher', '1.5'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'Optimizely-iOS-SDK'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'TLYShyNavBar'

use_frameworks!


Here charts is in Swift.

Comment: @technerd, I am using, so, is there any care to do regarding it?

Comment: Are you got any mail  regarding to App rejection reason with detailed description from iTunes server ? If yes then please share mail description so we will get exact idea .

Comment: Please edit your question with post rejection reason from Apple(If you got rejection mail) also, so it would be easier to find question to other users if they are facing same problem. Appreciate your efforts.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue when upload my application developed in swift and supports of Cocoapods as Dependency Manager.

When i upload build it shows exactly as you upload in Screen shot.

But when i update framework.sh file as given, my build accepted by Apple and my app is on App Store now.

Try to upload after comment given code in Pods-ProjectName-frameworks.sh file.

Comment bellow given code in  **Pods-ProjectName-frameworks.sh** file.

```
#   Embed linked Swift runtime libraries. No longer necessary as of Xcode 7.
if [ "${XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR}" -lt 7 ]; then
local swift_runtime_libs
swift_runtime_libs=$(xcrun otool -LX "$binary" | grep --color=never @rpath/libswift | sed -E s/@rpath\\/\(.+dylib\).*/\\1/g | uniq -u  && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
for lib in $swift_runtime_libs; do
  echo "rsync -auv \"${SWIFT_STDLIB_PATH}/${lib}\" \"${destination}\""
  rsync -auv "${SWIFT_STDLIB_PATH}/${lib}" "${destination}"
  code_sign_if_enabled "${destination}/${lib}"
done
fi
```

[image]
Hope it helps you.

Comment: but you code was written swift, supporting cocoapods, but my code is in Objective-C, having Swift Cocoa Pods and Objective C cocoa Pods. So, do you think will this work :)

Comment: It didn't help @technerd

Comment: Thats why i am saying that please check mail from iTunes Connect to know exact reason of rejection.

Comment: I solved it. This was not an issue. It accepted code without commenting above lines which you gave.

Comment: The issue which you wrote, was when cocoapod was not updated, now this issue is resolved by cocoapods.

Comment: @techerd, It was another issue, I was using some methods, which had same name as of Apple Own library :). So they were rejecting it.

Comment: @Sam Shaikh : Please post your answer so other will find it helpful.

Comment: I will update answer by evening after office hours, descriptively.  Thanks for help, also what you have provided is not resolved by CocoaPods. Thanks.